# Oracle thinks table doesn't exist during alter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to alter a column on a table with this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_SCHEMA.latest_workspace MODIFY (short_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Error starting at line 1 in command: ALTER TABLE
>   MY_SCHEMA.latest_workspace MODIFY (short_name VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL)
>   Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

However, I can physically see the table just fine and query it with:

```
SELECT short_name FROM MY_SCHEMA.latest_workspace;
```

Also, all the correct permissions are granted to the user that I am logged in with. Is there something else I'm forgetting that can cause this for an ALTER?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it definitely a table and not a view?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear `MY_SCHEMA.latest_workspace` is not a table.  It might be a view, or perhaps it's a synonym to an object in some other schema.  Try this query to find out:

```
select object_type
from   user_objects
where object_name = 'LATEST_WORKSPACE';
```

The action you need to take subsequently depends on the result.

Comment: You were both right. They are using workspace manager for some parts of the database and I was mistaking this view for a version enabled table (stupid mondays).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve this problem was recreate the table.
(Rename, drop constraints and indexes, recreate the original table, insert records).

Can´t find the reason, but sounds me like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but it was because the tables were in different schemas. I dropped one table and created it in the same schema, so it worked.